# What are the "theoretical risks" of COVID vaccines in mothers

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, coronavirus

In Germany, there is no official endorsement of COVID mRNA vaccines for pregnant women and nursing mothers due to a lack of study data. Still, professional societies generally recommend considering the vaccines for this population, as there is no known harmful mechanism for those vaccines that would be concerning, and the benefits would vastly outweigh any "theoretical risk". I was, however, unable to find any sources on what these "theoretical risks" could be, aside from "something happens we had no idea could happen". The mRNA surely isn't gonna cause problems. Are there any known theoretical risks for any of the components, e.g. adverse effects only observed in high dosage etc.?